# Error creating Hibernate Mapping Files and PJOS from Database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I use java version 8.0.2 and Mysql Gui 9:02 software.I try to create Hibernate Mapping Files and PJOS from Database but I always get the following error message

**Hibernate configuration fails with message:
Could not get list of suggested identity strategies from database. Probably a JDBC driver problem. 
see message.log for exception details.**

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mind_1.0.2?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Please Help Me!

[image]

Comment: What the server do you use?

Comment: can you attach the hibernate cfg.xml  to your question ??

Comment: try to add JDBC drivers in your project, it is needed in Hibernate

Comment: @Madushan Perera Well I've added hibernate cfg.xml

Comment: you dont have the property `<property name="hibernate.connection.password">your_passowrd_here</property>`

Comment: Try to add the password property and  perform the task again. If no success delete configuration file , reverse engineering file and  try again..

Comment: Sadly I tried again but it failed.

Comment: Thank all of you for helping me,I have solved the problem by formatting my name database has special characters should hibernate not handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your database name is not right.
And try to add

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</property>
```

Comment: The name of my database is Exactly .But hibernate don't accept format my name is  "_1.0.2" than I have a new name and change successfully. Thank you suggested to me

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed the db password tag.

> ```
> <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
> ```

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBname
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: That is one case . But again he had a problem with his DB name which was not in the format of hibernate accept.